# Create a custom signal filter in Python scipy

Tags: python, filter, signal-processing

I am trying to implement the following filter using python and scipy.
I already know how to implement "basic" filter like this:

```
cut_freq = 0.05
b, a = scipy.signal.butter(1, cut_freq/(fs/2), 'high')
output_signal = scipy.signal.filtfilt(b, a, flicker) # flicker is just a random signal in numpy
```

However the filter at hand is much more complex and I don't know how to attack the problem. Thanks !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stick to using scipy [filtfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html) function then you need to pass in the numerator and denumerator coefficients in b and a, which would be somwhat messy (i'd rather do an fft on the signal then multiply by the evaluated frequency response).

a good way to expand the expression and obtain b and a is using [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), by writing it as text

```py
sympy.sympify('expression')
```

and evaluating the expression obtained on all other variables except s (using [expr.subs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html)) then simplifying using [cancel](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html) on 's' as the variable to cancel on,  to be left with only b and a.